# Recibir dato como parámetro en Django

Tags: python, django, mvc, parametros

Estoy realizando captura de datos de un paciente por medio del siguiente método en el controller:

```
    @login_required
def registrarpaciente(request):
    dataCURP = None
    template = 'views/pacientes/registrarpaciente.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrarPaciente(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            CURP = form.cleaned_data.get('CURP')
            CURPpac = pacientes.objects.filter(CURP = CURP)
            for item in CURPpac:
                dataCURP = item.CURP
            if dataCURP != None:
                context_pac = {'form': form, 'error':'El paciente ya se encuentra registrado.'}
                return render(request, template, context_pac)
            else:
                Nombre_Pac = form.cleaned_data.get('Nombre_Pac')
                Apellidos_Pac = form.cleaned_data.get('Apellidos_Pac')
                FechaNac = form.cleaned_data.get('FechaNac')
                Peso = form.cleaned_data.get('Peso')
                Talla = form.cleaned_data.get('Talla')
                CURP = form.cleaned_data.get('CURP')
                Telefono = form.cleaned_data.get('Telefono')
                Sexo = form.cleaned_data.get('Sexo')
                Id_EdoCivil_id = form.cleaned_data.get('Id_EdoCivil_id')
                Newpaciente = pacientes(Nombre_Pac=Nombre_Pac, Apellidos_Pac=Apellidos_Pac, FechaNac=FechaNac, Peso=Peso, Talla=Talla, CURP=CURP,Telefono=Telefono, Sexo=Sexo, Id_EdoCivil_id=Id_EdoCivil_id)
                Newpaciente.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('registrardomicilio/str:CURP/')
        else:
            context_pac = {'form': form}
            return render(request, template, context_pac)
    else:
        context_pac = {'form': RegistrarPaciente()}
        return render(request, template, context_pac)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando registro mi paciente, me envía a capturar su domicilio, pero debo recibir como parámetro la CURP del paciente en cuestión.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo envío la CURP como parámetro a otro método (Domicilios) el cual tiene relacionado este campo, para capturar los datos de domicilio de este paciente?

Así luce mi método de registro de domicilio y mi urls.py.

```
    def registrardomicilio(request, CURP):
    dataDOM = None
    template = 'views/pacientes/registrardomicilio.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrarDomicilio(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            CURP = form.cleaned_data.get('CURP')
            CURPdom = domicilios.objects.filter(CURP = CURP)
            for item in CURPdom:
                dataDOM = item.CURP
            if dataDOM != None:
                context_domicilio = {'form': form, 'error':'El paciente ya cuenta con domicilio registrado.'}
                return render(request, template, context_domicilio)
            else:
                CURP = form.cleaned_data.get('CURP')
                Calle = form.cleaned_data.get('Calle')
                NumInt = form.cleaned_data.get('NumInt')
                NumExt = form.cleaned_data.get('NumExt')
                Colonia = form.cleaned_data.get('Colonia')
                CP = form.cleaned_data.get('CP')
                Municipio = form.cleaned_data.get('Municipio')
                Estado = form.cleaned_data.get('Estado')
                Newdomicilio = domicilios()
                Newdomicilio.CURP = pacientes.objects.get(CURP = request.POST['CURP'])
                Newdomicilio.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('pacientes')
        else:
            context_domicilio = {'form': form}
            return render(request, template, context_domicilio)
    else:
        context_domicilio = {'form': RegistrarDomicilio()}
        return render(request, template, context_domicilio)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en la vista `registrarpaciente`, específicamente en la siguiente linea:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('registrardomicilio/str:CURP/')
```

No le estas pasando ningún parámetro a la URL, en todo caso seria así:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(f'registrardomicilio/{ CURP }/')
```

Pero la mejor practica seria que Django se encarge de generar la URL y de pasar los parámetros a este:

```
# from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect('registrardomicilio', CURP = CURP)
```

Si quieres saber mas de `redirect` revisa la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). Espero haberte ayudado.